# dropdown selector in R Markdown html output without Shniy?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Is it possible to add a dropdown selector in R Markdown html output? I do not want to use Shiny because I want it to be functional without a server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1116
Save this as tabset-dropdown.html in your working directory:

```
<style>
/* Notwendiges Zeug für Dropdowns */
.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-height: 44px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li.active:before {
    content: "";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs.nav-tabs-open > li.active:before {
    content: "&#xe258;";
    border: none;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs.nav-tabs-open:before {
    content: "";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}


.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li.active {
    display: block;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus,
.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs.nav-tabs-open > li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabset-dropdown > .nav-tabs > li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-tabs-open')
    });
}); 
</script>
```

The corresponding rmarkdown code is:

````
---
  title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
  toc: true
toc_float: true
code_folding: hide
number_sections: true
includes:
  after_body: tabset-dropdown.html
---
  
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# R Markdown {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

## Tab A

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

## Tab B
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
  
  ## Tab C
  ```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:
  
  ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

[image]